# Where did these Monochrome Thunderbird icons come from?

Tags: 11.10, unity, themes, icons, thunderbird

I'm running Thunderbird 8 on Ubuntu 11.10, and I'm stuck with these monochrome toolbar buttons that I hate. If I look under `Tools > Add Ons > Appearance` I've only got the default theme installed and the sample icons are full color. The icons I'm seeing are decidedly *not* full color. I was able to install the Gnome Tweak Tool which let met change the rest of my Unity icons to full color by switching the "icon theme" to "Unity-icon-theme" (it was Unity-mono-dark). Now only my Thunderbird icons are monochrome.

How is Unity overriding the default Thunderbird theme?

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is part of the default theme according to [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1848323.html)

The solution offered is to download another theme [from the gallery](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/themes/).

Comment: I still don't believe this. When I look in my themes, the preview of "default" has colored icons!

Answer (score 1):

While this is not a completely reasonable solution it is possible to restore the old icon set by [downloading a copy of Thunderbird for Linux](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/).  Decompress the application and then copy "omni.ja" out of the new "thunderbird" folder into your local install of Thunderbird (On my system this was `/usr/lib/thunderbird-11.0`).  This should undo the default Ubuntu theme.

WARNING: I have no idea if it is necessary to download the EXACT same version of Thunderbird that is already installed in order for this trick to work.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to isolate omni.ja from a Thunderbird source repository?